# PyOrient client reports protocol version error when trying to connect to server

Tags: orientdb

I'm getting what appears to be a version mismatch error from client.connect() when using what I believe to be the most recent versions of pyorient and the orientdb server

> Protocol version 37 is not supported yet by this client.

Is there a more up-to-date version of pyclient available?

here's the test script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pyorient

client = pyorient.OrientDB( "localhost", 2424 )

session_id = client.connect( "root", "password" )
```

Here's the full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test1.py", line 7, in <module>
    session_id = client.connect( "root", "D1sOri3nted" )
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyorient-1.5.5-py2.7.egg/pyorient/orient.py", line 325, in connect
    return self.get_message("ConnectMessage") \
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyorient-1.5.5-py2.7.egg/pyorient/orient.py", line 540, in get_message
    message_instance = _Message(self._connection)\
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyorient-1.5.5-py2.7.egg/pyorient/messages/connection.py", line 17, in __init__
    super( ConnectMessage, self ).__init__(_orient_socket)
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyorient-1.5.5-py2.7.egg/pyorient/messages/base.py", line 24, in __init__
    sock.get_connection()
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyorient-1.5.5-py2.7.egg/pyorient/orient.py", line 78, in get_connection
self.connect()
  File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyorient-1.5.5-py2.7.egg/pyorient/orient.py", line 103, in connect
    " is not supported yet by this client.", [])
pyorient.exceptions.PyOrientWrongProtocolVersionException: Protocol version 37 is not supported yet by this client.
```

I'm using the pyorient version from https://github.com/orientechnologies/pyorient

The server comes from the distributed docker image.
I'm uncertain of how to get the server version, but from *within* the docker container the console reports v3.0.1

Thanks in advance for any help or advice on this!

Comment: Did you read [this](https://github.com/mogui/pyorient/issues/270) GitHub issue?

Comment: I had not!  Thank you for that reference!

Comment: and I can confirm that the client does connect with that version. Thank you again!

Comment: This is back again and I am still on ODB 3.1.1, not the latest if you just do the `pip install pyorient`